# What's the right place for a hook to delete my typescript files?

Tags: cordova

My cordova app code is written in typescript but there is no reason these files should end up in the APK file.

But should I put the script to delete these files in: before_build, before_clean, before_compile, before_prepare, before_run? Or in their respective 'after_' versions?

The Github cordova-cli repo just points to here:
[Apache.org Hooks Guide](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/guide_appdev_hooks_index.md.html#Hooks%20Guide)
But that page doesn't describe each stage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably a few answers to this question, but I guess that depends on how / when you are converting your typescript files to javascript (as even that process could be done with hooks with the before_prepare hook.)  The short answer is either after_prepare or before_compile.

Let us look at the cli commands for prepare, compile and build ([source](https://github.com/apache/cordova-cli/#project-commands)):

```
prepare [platform...] copies files into the specified platforms, or all platforms. 
    It is then ready for building by Eclipse, Xcode, etc.

compile [platform...] compiles the app into a binary for each targetted platform. 
    With no parameters, builds for all platforms, otherwise builds for the 
    specified platforms. 

build [<platform> [<platform> [...]]] an alias for cordova prepare followed 
    by cordova compile
```

before_prepare and before_build will be too early, as the files haven't been copied over to the platform folder yet, and after_compile and after_build will be too late as the package will have been generated.  This leaves after_prepare and before_compile as the opportune time to adjust files going into your packages.

However, I think there is a nice alternative solution as well.  Create a separate folder in the project root, something like `typescript/`.  This is where your typescript files will live.  Create a before_prepare hook to generate your javascript files in the appropriate `www/` location.  This way the build process will automatically generate your files, and since your typescript files would not live in the `www/` folder, you will not have to remove any typescript files before generating the final package.

The [jade example](https://gist.github.com/dpogue/4100866) provided on the hooks documentation is a good starting point for the suggestion listed above (though the jade files are included this outlines the idea of generating the files on build. Again changing the starting location of the files to be outside the `www/` would resolve this)